# can i use assignement operator in methods parameters

Tags: ios, swift

```
open func open(_ url: URL, options: [String : Any] = [:], completionHandler completion: ((Bool) -> Swift.Void)? = nil)
```

because  i noticed that the open funtion in the UIapplication using assignment operator in their parameters is it possibe and some one please elobrate what is happening in the above line of code and explain each and every elements for me

Comment: In open function default value gets assigned to options parameter.

Comment: Please read about Default Parameter Vakues in the Swift book https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166

Answer (score 0):

You can define a default value for any parameter in a function by assigning a value to the parameter after that parameter’s type. If a default value is defined, you can omit that parameter when calling the function.

```
 func someFunction(parameterWithoutDefault: Int, parameterWithDefault: Int = 12) {
// If you omit the second argument when calling this function, then
// the value of parameterWithDefault is 12 inside the function body.
}


someFunction(parameterWithoutDefault: 3, parameterWithDefault: 6) //parameterWithDefault is 6
someFunction(parameterWithoutDefault: 4) // parameterWithDefault is 12
```

Comment: must i want to pass values when default is not given ?

Comment: @velsserver Yes exactly